# reload javasript

Tags: javascript

boa tarde,

gostaria de uma ajuda referente ao meu reload, acontece que eu tenho uma função que alimenta a minha view e no final dela dentro de um intervalo de tempo de 5 mim ele aplica o reload para que os dados sejam atualizados, porém existem filtros que eu posso selecionar como por exemplo um checkbox se eu seleciono um outro checkbox os dados carregam de acordo com a opção que eu selecionei porém depois do reload ele perde os dados voltando para os dados de de inicio.

segue abaixo meu codigo:

```
function carregaDadosPagina(){                    

    vMostrar = vMostrar === "" ? 'ped': vMostrar;  

    var ini = data_inicial;
    var uni = unidades;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/pedidos/getStatus',
        type: "get",
        data: {tipo: vMostrar, ini: ini, uni: uni},
        success: function (data) {

            //console.log(data);

            if (data !== ""){

                data = JSON.parse(data);

                dadosTela = data;

                // console.log(dadosTela);

                var vlr_ativos = dadosTela.geral.vlr_ativos;
                var vlr_concluidos = dadosTela.geral.vlr_concluidos;
                var vlr_iniciar = dadosTela.geral.vlr_iniciar;
                var vlr_processo = dadosTela.geral.vlr_processo;

                // console.log(vlr_ativos, vlr_concluidos, vlr_iniciar, vlr_processo);

                /*vlr_ativos = validaValores(vlr_ativos);
                vlr_concluidos = validaValores(vlr_concluidos);
                vlr_iniciar = validaValores(vlr_iniciar);                                          
                vlr_processo = validaValores(vlr_processo);*/

                //alert(vlr_processo);

                vlr_ativos = abbreviateNumber(vlr_ativos);
                vlr_concluidos = abbreviateNumber(vlr_concluidos);
                vlr_iniciar = abbreviateNumber(vlr_iniciar);                                          
                vlr_processo = abbreviateNumber(vlr_processo);

                //ativos
                $("#qtd1").html(dadosTela.geral.ativos);
                $("#valor1").html(vlr_ativos);
                //iniciar                                
                $("#qtd2").html(dadosTela.geral.iniciar);
                $("#valor2").html(vlr_iniciar);
                //processando
                $("#qtd3").html(dadosTela.geral.processo);
                $("#valor3").html(vlr_processo);
                //concluídos
                $("#qtd4").html(dadosTela.geral.concluidos);
                $("#valor4").html(vlr_concluidos);                                                        

                var conclusao = Math.round(dadosTela.geral.percent_conc);
                $('.doughnut.doughnut-50').css({'background-image':'linear-gradient(270deg,#59829a  ' + conclusao + '%,transparent 0,transparent),linear-gradient(270deg,#59829a  '+ conclusao +'%,#fafafa 0,#fafafa)'}); 

                //conclusão
                $("div").attr('data-label', conclusao + '%');
                //previstos
                $("#prev").html(dadosTela.geral.previstos);
                $('#prev').attr('data-end', dadosTela.geral.previstos);  

                //erro_proc_sap
                $("#erro_proc_sap").html(dadosTela.geral.erro_proc_sap);
                $("#erro_proc_sap").attr('data-end', dadosTela.geral.erro_proc_sap);
                //cancelados
                $("#canc").html(dadosTela.geral.cancelado);
                $("#canc").attr('data-end', dadosTela.geral.cancelado);
                //nao carregados
                $("#n_carr_data").html(dadosTela.geral.n_carr_data);
                $("#n_carr_data").attr('data-end', dadosTela.geral.n_carr_data);


                carregaGraficos();


            } else {
                alert("Sem resultado!");
            }

            startRefreshInfo = true;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar os dados.");
        }
    });
}

startRefreshInfo = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    carregaDadosPagina();

    $("input[name='fat_ambev']").click(function(){

        vMostrar = $(this).val();

        carregaDadosPagina(vMostrar);
    });

    // buscar = window.open('test');

    $("#buscar").click(function(){

        data_inicial = $("#date").val();
        unidades = $("#unidades").val();

        carregaDadosPagina();                           

    });

    setInterval(function(){
        window.location.reload(true);                            
    }, 30000);

});
```

Comment: Ao fazer o reload vc deveria pegar os dados atualizados pelo PHP (se usa PHP).

Comment: Você não precisa recarregar a página já que está usando ajax. Basta chamar `carregaDadosPagina()` dentro do loop